# While clicking on the View Button in dialogue box it's not Finding element in selenium webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOnLq.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOnLq.jpg)****This Page is developed in C#(asp.net)*****

[enter image description here][2]On That Page only one Dialog Box's Close button is working and other Dialog Box's close button is not working and vice versa.

//Closing Training view button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/button/span")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);

[![https][2]][2]

Error in Eclipse::

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with Command duration
>   or timeout: 10.05 seconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision:
>   '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40' System info: host:
>   'BISHNUPRASAD', ip: '172.16.12.108', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45' Session ID:
>   e35dda6a-1c9b-4345-8412-c225a0ebeba3 Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true,
>   rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=43.0.1}]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>     at ARMS.Amiri.main(Amiri.java:93) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible and so may not be interacted with Build info:
>   version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
>   System info: host: 'BISHNUPRASAD', ip: '172.16.12.108', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_45' Driver info: driver.version: unknown   at .fxdriver.preconditions.visible(file:///C:/Users/bishnu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5983937291135292550webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:10092)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_(file:///C:/Users/bishnu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5983937291135292550webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12644)
>     at .DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h(file:///C:/Users/bishnu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5983937291135292550webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
>     at .fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///C:/Users/bishnu/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5983937291135292550webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:625)

Comment: try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Button[@title='Close']")).click();

Comment: this is a common error, you need to check manually the selector to see if is visible or not

Answer (score 0):

Possible that you have another button that is hidden and the first button found is that one.
You can try with a simple css like this:

```css
div[style*=block] button.ui-widget.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
```